# UIButton TouchUpInside Touch Location

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touch, uitouch, sender

So I have a large `UIButton`, it is a `UIButtonTypeCustom`, and the button target is called for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.  My question is how can I determine where in the `UIButton` the touch occured.  I want this info so I can display a popup from the touch location.  Here is what I've tried:

```
UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint where = [theTouch locationInView:self];
NSLog(@" touch at (%3.2f, %3.2f)", where.x, where.y);
```

and various other iterations.  The button's target method get info from it via the `sender`:

```
    UIButton *button = sender;
```

So is there any way I could use something like: `button.touchUpLocation`?

I looked online and couldn't find anything similar to this so thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no touchUpLocation, UIButton is a control you can not get the location of UIButton click. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Comment: I didn't mean literally touchUpLocation, I meant something like that

Comment: @Praveen-K, that's incorrect. UIKit supports actions that take a second parameter, the UIEvent which triggered the action. From that you can get the list of touches, and each touch has a location. See the code I posted below. It's true that UIButton doesn't have a method that returns the location of the last click, however.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint where = [theTouch locationInView:self];
NSLog(@" touch at (%3.2f, %3.2f)", where.x, where.y);
```

That's the right idea, except that this code is probably inside an action in your view controller, right? If so, then `self` refers to the view controller and not the button. You should be passing a pointer to the button into `-locationInView:`.

Here's a tested action that you can try in your view controller:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView *button = (UIView *)sender;
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    NSLog(@"Location in button: %f, %f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that completely solved my problem.  I thought it couldn't be done, so this is great.

Comment: What a great snippet of code - sometimes these things show up which reaffirm your belief in human nature :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get the event from `- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender` ...?  (That is, I have a huge project and I'd like to bottleneck this, without changing all the buttons to `...forEvent:`, if I can.)  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie As far as I know, if you want the event you'll need to change the signature of the action to include the event parameter.

Comment: but if you got multiple touches, this doesn't get you any further

Comment: @PeterLapisu Of course it does. The point of the answer is that the OP needed to specify the button rather than `self` in the call to `-locationInView:`. I used `-anyObject` because that's what the OP used, but there's nothing to prevent you from looking at each touch in the set of touches: `NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:button]; for (UITouch *t in touches) {CGPoint p = [t locationInView:button]; ...}`. But, again, the OP's question isn't about how to handle multiple touches.

Comment: Great! This answer save me a lot of time!By the way,if you want location in the view controller that the button belongs,you can:CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view]; or something

Answer (score 7):

**For Swift 3.0:**

```
@IBAction func buyTap(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) 
{
       let myButton:UIButton = sender as! UIButton
       let touches: Set<UITouch>? = event.touches(for: myButton)
       let touch: UITouch? = touches?.first
       let touchPoint: CGPoint? = touch?.location(in: myButton)
       print("touchPoint\(touchPoint)")  
}
```