# how to create a custom indexing

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, custom-controls

[image]

How can I create a custom indexing like this. I have tried to give a image & color in the back but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

See [UIButton TouchUpInside Touch Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374937/uibutton-touchupinside-touch-location) - it's as easy as having a custom buttom with 26 * n pixel height, the y-value divided by 26 and converted to a character will give you the index.

Comment: ya i can detect the tap event of custom button how to add these button in table view and 2. it didn't show the scroll effect as we have in table view indexing...

Comment: This button must not be part of the tableview. You want it to stay always on the right side of the screen at a fixed position, or not?

Comment: Its create a problem suppose I don't have header with name of "w" so I don't even need that in indexing..cant we customize table view indexing..

Comment: If someone clicks on `W` you could show an UIAlertView with the following text: `If you click on W once more, the app will crash`. Or you could treat it simply as no-op, when there are no entries with W.