# Is it possible to get the exact location of a button click in an iOS code (swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I am trying to implement a CustomKeyboard as an application extension to my iOS device. What I need is the exact click location on buttons. Some users may click a little to the edge, whereas some click right in the middle of the buttons. 
Is there a way do achieve that?

I am trying to write it in Swift but objective-c is ok too

[Getting the coordinates from the location I touch the touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829295/swift-getting-the-coordinates-from-the-location-i-touch-the-touchscreen) mentions a similar thing, but I need the coordinates from the button event, not some image. 
Steve's link seems to be the answer tho. I will try that one. Thanks
I

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374937/uibutton-touchupinside-touch-location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829295/swift-getting-the-coordinates-from-the-location-i-touch-the-touchscreen

Answer (score 2):

One of the optional method signatures for an IBAction takes a UIEvent:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

Or in Swift:

```
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

For touch events like a TouchUpInside event, the event will be a Touch event. A touch event will include one or more `UITouch` objects. You can get the touch's coordinates in the target view from the `UITouch` object.