# How to disable TouchUpInside Action outside the boundary of button

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

This is my Xib. I just dragged a UIButton and changed its background color.

[image]

I created a semi circle layer using this code

```
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPointMake(mybutton.bounds.size.width / 4, 0), radius: mybutton.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath
    mybutton.layer.mask = circleShape
```

and this is my output.

[image]

Its perfect as I want it. But the problem is that  this button is clickable outside its rounded area(as per actuall shape of button). I want it to be clickable only as rounded shape.

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: sanman's approach would work. you can also try to use hitTest:

Answer (score 8):

Create action of signature

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
//your code
}
```

for your button

Find out touch location using this answer
[UIButton TouchUpInside Touch Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374937/uibutton-touchupinside-touch-location)

Check if that location is contained in your CGPath using

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
  //find location point using above answer link
  if([button.layer.mask containsPoint: location])
  {
   //proceed with the code
  }
}
```

it returns a bool if it contains point.

i.e if it contains point you can proceed otherwise you can return.

Hope it helps :)